# How do I generate a new array that each element is the the maximum number within a local range of a numpy 1d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 1D array in numpy. Let's say `x=np.arange(20)`

I want to generate a new array that each element is the the maximum number of x in range `[i:i+4],i=0..15,step=5`

in this case, `new_array=[x[0:4].max(), x[5:9].max(), x[10:14].max(),x[15:19].max()]=[4,9,14,19]`

but I want to create a universe routine that can process arbitrary range. now I am using forloop to do that, but does there exist any shortcut?

Comment: `x.reshape((-1, 5)).max(axis=1)`

Comment: I think you meant `[x[0:5].max(), x[5:10].max(), x[10:15].max(), x[15:20].max()]` for a step of 5 and to get your expected `[4,9,14,19]`

Comment: @HenryEcker Yeah you are right

Comment: Your comment looks like an answer @Psidom, maybe move it to one

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a list comprehension for that if you don't want to write a function. Following the example you gave:

```
new_array = [x[i:i+4].max() for i in range(0, 15+1, 5)]
```

This would generate [3, 8, 13, 18], *not* [4, 9, 14, 19]. Remember that the upper index is not considered when slicing an array. That is also the reason I put "15+1" in the range function.

A generalization for vectors of any size using this method would be something like:

```
new_array = [x[i:i+4].max() for i in range(0, x.size-4, 5)]
```